# Javascript best price depending on quantity code alternative

Tags: javascript

Anyone can suggest a way of achieving the same outcome of the math with a loop or if statements or something similar ? Just trying to learn different approaches to he same problem.

It needs to calculate best price from qty so if qty is 5, then the price would be price of 2 and price of 3.

```
// get inputs

  let qty = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

// base prices

  let price = 6.45;
  let price2 = 12.0;
  let price3 = 14.0;
 
    //calc total with best deal

    let total1 = Math.floor((qty % 3) % 2) * price;
    let total2 = Math.floor((qty % 3) / 2) * price2;
    let total3 = Math.floor(qty / 3) * price3;
    let totalPrice = total1 + total2 + total3;
```

Comment: If this is a follow-up question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969952/application-that-calculates-price-depending-on-quantity-in-javascript, you might want to add some background info to make this question itself clear

Comment: Yep I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why are you using modulo?

Comment: I don't see an `if` condition. `%` is the remainder operator after division by that number.

Comment: @lastr2d2 I just wanted to separate this one from the original one to get a different approach to the math. I am using the Modulo to get the remainder of the input number divided by 3 to see how many 3s are in that number and store the correct price in the total1,2,3 variables for the calculation at the end.

Comment: it's great to make it a sperate question, it would be even great to put some effort to make it clear to someone who don't know the other one... for example, describe what's the best price, how does the current calculation work, what's the expected result etc

Comment: @lastr2d2 Good point my friend. Thank you for the feedback. I will put that in mind next time for sure 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this more general approach:

```js
let qty = 10;

// Each element a[i] represents the price of buying a quantity of i+1 items.
let bundlePrices = [6.45, 12.0, 14.0];

let totalPrice = 0;

while (qty > 0) {
    let itemsInBundle = bundlePrices.length
    let bundlePrice = bundlePrices[bundlePrices.length - 1];
    let numBundles = Math.floor(qty / itemsInBundle);
    totalPrice += numBundles * bundlePrice;

    qty -= numBundles * itemsInBundle;
    bundlePrices.pop();
}

console.log(totalPrice);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Michael Horn This is very helpful